# A synchronization primitive with increased owner thread priority

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, synchronization, thread-priority

I have a program where sometimes bursts happen so that threads would load the CPU above 100% if that was possible, but in reality, they fight for the CPU. It is critical that a thread obtaining ownership of a synchronization primitive gets a higher priority than the other threads of the application, so to prevent the case where a thread obtains ownership and gets paused by the scheduler. Is there a suitable synchronization primitive in C++ (up to the latest draft) or WinAPI, or do I have to wrap the mutex locking code in `SetThreadPriority()` calls?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually a problem. If a thread that owns a synchronization primitive gets paused by the scheduler, it would only be because there were enough ready-to-run threads to keep all the cores busy. In that case, there's no particular reason to care which thread runs.

Threads that waiting for the synchronization primitive aren't ready to run. So if you have four cores and the thread that holds the synchronization primitive isn't being blocked, it would only be because there are four threads, all ready-to-run, that can make forward progress without holding the synchronization primitive. In that case, running those four threads is just as good as running the thread that holds the synchronization primitive.

I strongly urge you not to mess with thread priorities unless you really have no choice. Once you start messing with thread priorities, the argument above can stop holding because you can get issues like priority inversion. But if you don't mess with thread priorities, then you can't run into those kinds of issues and the scheduler will be smart enough to do the right thing 99% of the time. And trying to mess with priorities to get it do the right thing that last 1% of the time will likely backfire.

Comment: Some threads are more important because they populate the queues of work for the other threads. And the processing times are not equal: thread A has to spend 1 second to produce 10 seconds of work for thread B.

Comment: @SergeRogatch Those things will never be an issue for two reasons: 1) If any ready-to-run thread is not being scheduled, there's currently enough work to go around. 2) Every thread will get roughly the same amount of time when there's work to be done, so the threads that need less time to make work will not get starved. (The scheduler is smart. Let it to do its job.)

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you are looking for is called a *priority inheritance protocol*.  Pthreads offers support for this sort of configuration, and the idea is that if a high priority task is waiting for a resource held by a low priority task, the low priority task is boosted to that high priority until it relinquishes the resource.

Search for Liu and Layland, they wrote most of this up in the early 70s.  As for C++, I am afraid it is a few versions away from 1973's state of the art.